# What is the math behind Adobe Illustrator Freedom Gradient

Tags: math, colors, gradient, adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Illustrator, you can apply a free form gradient to shapes by placing an n amount of colors in the shape. I'm trying to replicate that behavior in a project I'm working on but I'm having a hard time figuring out how it works.

Here's a simple example:

[image]

In this case, there are 4 points of color (red, orange, blue, and cyan) and using the eyedrop tool, it seems like the center of the cross is the distance-weighted mean of the rgb values of the given color points.

However, where I'm starting to have issues is in a case like this:

[image]

As you can see, the point "A" doesn't seem to be affect by the Blue color as if it is blocked by the green color above it. Also, The teal color cannot reach the other side so there is also some blocking occurring at the shape edges.

What can I do to achieve a similar effect? What is the best way to compute a gradient in a shape given n color points?